# Transpose data in SQL Server Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transpose

I am wondering if there is a better way to write this query.  It achieves the target result but my colleague would prefer it be written without the subselects into temp tables t1-t3.  The main "challenge" here is transposing the data from dbo.ReviewsData into a single row along with the rest of the data joined from dbo.Prodcucts and dbo.Reviews.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Products (
idProduct int identity,
product_title varchar(100)
PRIMARY KEY (idProduct)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Products VALUES
(1001, 'poptart'),
(1002, 'coat hanger'),
(1003, 'sunglasses');

CREATE TABLE dbo.Reviews (
Rev_IDReview int identity,
Rev_IDProduct int
PRIMARY KEY (Rev_IDReview)
FOREIGN KEY (Rev_IDProduct) REFERENCES dbo.Products(idProduct)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.Reviews VALUES
(456, 1001),
(457, 1002),
(458, 1003);

CREATE TABLE dbo.ReviewFields (
RF_IDField int identity,
RF_FieldName varchar(32),
PRIMARY KEY (RF_IDField)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.ReviewFields VALUES
(1, 'Customer Name'),
(2, 'Review Title'),
(3, 'Review Message');

CREATE TABLE dbo.ReviewData (
RD_idData int identity,
RD_IDReview int,
RD_IDField int,
RD_FieldContent varchar(100)
PRIMARY KEY (RD_idData)
FOREIGN KEY (RD_IDReview) REFERENCES dbo.Reviews(Rev_IDReview)
);
INSERT INTO dbo.ReviewData VALUES
(79, 456, 1, 'Daniel'),
(80, 456, 2, 'Love this item!'),
(81, 456, 3, 'Works well...blah blah'),
(82, 457, 1, 'Joe!'),
(84, 457, 2, 'Pure Trash'),
(85, 457, 3, 'It was literally a used banana peel'),
(86, 458, 1, 'Karen'),
(87, 458, 2, 'Could be better'),
(88, 458, 3, 'I can always find something wrong');        

SELECT P.product_title as "item", t1.ReviewedBy, t2.ReviewTitle, t3.ReviewContent
        FROM dbo.Reviews R
        
        INNER JOIN dbo.Products P
        ON P.idProduct = R.Rev_IDProduct
        
        INNER JOIN (
           SELECT D.RD_FieldContent AS "ReviewedBy", D.RD_IDReview
           FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
           WHERE D.RD_IDField = 1
        ) t1
        ON t1.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview
        
        INNER JOIN (
           SELECT D.RD_FieldContent AS "ReviewTitle", D.RD_IDReview
           FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
           WHERE D.RD_IDField = 2
        ) t2
        ON t2.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview
        
        INNER JOIN (
           SELECT D.RD_FieldContent AS "ReviewContent", D.RD_IDReview
           FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
           WHERE D.RD_IDField = 3
        ) t3
        ON t3.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview
```

EDIT: I have updated this post with the create statements for the tables as opposed to an image of the data (shame on me) and a more specific description of what exactly needed to be improved.  Thanks to all for the comments and patience.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Specifically what about it makes them "uncomfortable"? If it does what you want and performs OK, then there should be nothing to worry about.

Comment: The only thing that makes me feel uncomfortable is the use of double quotes; other than that it looks like perfectly valid SQL.

Comment: yes thanks @DaleK I will have to edit the post with scripted creates for the sample data set to adhere to community guidelines.  I agree with your assessment but my colleague(/superior) says it looks weird without giving me much time to explain why I think it needs to be this way.  Sounds like its less of a technical problem and more of a bureaucratic one?

Comment: You could simplify it, you don't need a sub-query for each join, just join the table and add your where clause to the join clause, it will look much shorter and neater :)

Comment: `Sounds like its less of a technical problem and more of a bureaucratic one` : We cannot help you with internal Bureaucracy, but we can help you with improving queries, if you will provide the tools to reproduce the scenario. For this we need queries to create the tables including all indexes, triggers relations between the tables, constraint (these impact the query which will be selected. In addition we need the actual full (xml and not image) Execution Plan which your server uses when execute the query. (queries to create the table and insert sample data is the minimum to start discussion)

Comment: If the combination (RD_IDReview, RD_IDField) is unique, you could use conditional aggregation with one pass of ReviewsData `SELECT RD_IDReview, MAX(CASE WHEN RD_IDField = 1 THEN RD_FieldContent END) as ReviewedBy, ... GROUP BY RD_IDReview`

Comment: @Fred - you could equivalently use `PIVOT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in comments, there is nothing objectively wrong with the query. However, you could argue that it's verbose and hard to read.

One way to shorten it is to replace `INNER JOIN` with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT D.RD_FieldContent AS 'ReviewedBy', D.RD_IDReview
       FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
       WHERE D.RD_IDField = 1
    ) t1
    ON t1.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview
```

`APPLY` lets you refer to values from the outer query, like in a subquery:

```
    CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT D.RD_FieldContent AS 'ReviewedBy'
       FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
       WHERE D.RD_IDField = 1 AND D.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview
    ) t1
```

I think of `APPLY` like a subquery that brings in new columns. It's like a cross between a subquery and a join. Benefits:

- The query can be shorter, because you don't have to repeat the ID column twice.
- You don't have to expose columns that you don't need.

Disadvantages:

- If the query in the `APPLY` references outer values, then you can't extract it and run it all by itself without modifications.
- `APPLY` is specific to Sql Server and it's not that widely-used.

Another thing to consider is using subqueries instead of joins for values that you only need in one place. Benefits:

- The queries can be made shorter, because you don't have to repeat the ID column twice, and you don't have to give the output columns unique aliases.
- You only have to look in one place to see the whole subquery.
- Subqueries can only return 1 row, so you can't accidentally create extra rows, if only 1 row is desired.

  ```
  SELECT
      P.product_title as 'item',

      (SELECT D.RD_FieldContent
         FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
         WHERE D.RD_IDField = 1 AND
               D.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview) as ReviewedBy,

      (SELECT D.RD_FieldContent
         FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
         WHERE D.RD_IDField = 2 AND
               D.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview) as ReviewTitle,   

      (SELECT D.RD_FieldContent
         FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
         WHERE D.RD_IDField = 3 AND
               D.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview) as ReviewContent

  FROM dbo.Reviews R
   INNER JOIN dbo.Products P ON P.idProduct = R.Rev_IDProduct
  ```

Edit:

It just occurred to me that you have made the joins themselves unnecessarily verbose (@Dale K actually already pointed this out in the comments):

```
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT D.RD_FieldContent AS 'ReviewedBy', D.RD_IDReview
       FROM dbo.ReviewsData D
       WHERE D.RD_IDField = 1
    ) t1
    ON t1.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview
```

Shorter:

```
    SELECT RevBy.RD_FieldContent AS 'ReviewedBy'
    ...
    INNER JOIN dbo.ReviewsData RevBy
                 ON RevBy.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview AND
                    RevBy.RD_IDField = 1
```

Comment: Of course *apply* is SQL Server syntax, the functional concept is known as a *lateral join* and is supported by most RDBMS vendors using the `lateral` keyword.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you for your time to make such a detailed explanation @NealBurns.  Experiences like this are what help ppl like me become more productive.

Answer (score 1):

The originally submitted query is undoubtedly and unnecessarily verbose.  Having digested various feedback from the community it has been revised to the following, working splendidly.  In retrospect I feel very silly for having done this with subselects originally.  I am clearly intermediate at best when it comes to SQL - I had not realized an "AND" clause could be included in the "ON" clause in a "JOIN" statement.  Not sure why I would have made such a poor assumption.

```
SELECT 
P.product_title as 'item',
D1.RD_FieldContent as 'ReviewedBy',
D2.RD_FieldContent as 'ReviewTitle',
D3.RD_FieldContent as 'ReviewContent'
FROM dbo.Reviews R
INNER JOIN dbo.Products P
ON P.idProduct = R.Rev_IDProduct
INNER JOIN dbo.ReviewsData D1
ON D1.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview AND D1.RD_IDField = 1
INNER JOIN dbo.ReviewsData D2
ON D2.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview AND D2.RD_IDField = 2
INNER JOIN dbo.ReviewsData D3
ON D3.RD_IDReview = R.Rev_IDReview AND D3.RD_IDField = 3
```

Comment: Not sure you've included the entire query here since you have no `p` alias; this is still incredibly wasteful since you hit the same table 3 times. Hit it once and `case` out your FieldContent.

Comment: Thanks @Stu.  I have updated to include the (P)roducts table.
CASE seems like the obvious way to handle something like this - I will see if I can figure out how to incorporate appropriately

Comment: @Stu incredibly wasteful of what? Performance? Screen space? I don't think it's possible to make it more efficient. We can look at execution plans.